Ubuntu 24.04 - Autoinstall and debconf-selections
I am trying to use autoinstall for the first time.
After first issues I was able to create a basic autoinstall.yaml and to install
a fresh system with that file.
Now I wanted to modify the autoinstall.yaml to install KDE next to Gnome.
In an interactive shell dpkg-reconfigure asks which display manager should be used.
To automate the answer I can use the keyword "debconf-selections", but whatever I try the installer tells me this error:
Malformed autoinstall in "debconf-selections" section
First the whole install file:
autoinstall:
  version: 1
  interactive-sections:
    - network
    - locale
    - keyboard
  identity:
    realname: 'Testuser'
    username: testuser
    hostname: 'my-special-pc'
    password: '$6$SomeHash'
  storage:
    layout:
      name: lvm
      sizing-policy: all
  codecs:
    install: true
  drivers:
    install: true
  oem:
    install: auto
  snaps:
    - name: brave
    - name: opera
  packages:
    - ansible
    - arandr
    - kubuntu-desktop
  debconf-selections:
    - d-i shared/default-x-display-manager select sddm
  timezone: geoip
  updates: all

Alternatives I tried and remember:
  debconf-selections:
    - sddm shared/default-x-display-manager select sddm

  debconf-selections:
    - shared/default-x-display-manager select sddm

What am I doing wrong?
P.S.: If there are other issues, I will deal with them later, but for now the autoinstall
works if I remove "debconf-selections".

The autoinstall configuration for debconf-selections is just a string and is easiest with a YAML multi-line format.
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  debconf-selections: |
    sddm shared/default-x-display-manager select sddm

I don't know if that is the correct debconf setting for what you are trying to accomplish.

Thank you, there was now not an syntax error, but the change did not work.
Well, need to find an other way around this.
